# How the Depletion Region is shrinked when Diode is in forward biased?

Tags: diodes

I would like to know why does the depletion region gets shrinked when a potential is given to a diode(Forward Bias).Is it because we have given a higher voltage than the voltage of the depletion region?But still how does that voltage turn out to break the depletion region?Could anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Without any voltage between the diode terminals there is an internal voltage across the pn junction caused by diffusion (diffusion voltage). This voltage leads to a stop of the diffusion process and causes a state of equilibrium - and results in a zone of depletion.
Now - when we connect a voltage between the outer terminals in a direction **opposite** to the diffusion voltage the depletion zone is shrinked because the outer voltage acts against the internal diffusion voltage (two voltages in series with different polarities). The polarity of this voltage is called "forward bias".

Comment: :Thanks for your answer.But could you explain what do you meant by:"outer voltage acts against the internal diffusion voltage" and the "two voltages in series".I'm just learning about diodes.

Comment: The internally developped diffusion voltage Vd is directed from the n region to the p region (from "+" to "-") because  the n region has lost electrons due to diffusion. If the external voltage is directed from the p region to the n region it has an opposite direction to the diffusion voltage and reduces the state of equilibrium and, thus, the depletion zone.

Comment: :But isn't external voltage connected as negative to n region and positive to p region or whether it's opposite as you said?

Comment: In the n-region we have a POSITIVE space charge because electrons (majorities) were moving into the p-region. And we connect the external voltage with its NEGATIVE side to the n-region. Thus, electrons are injected into this region and form/allow the current in "forward" direction.

Comment: :Could you say which region you stated while saying about "electrons are injected into this region".

Comment: ..."into this region" means, of course, into the zone that is n-doped (because the negative side of the external source is connected to it).

Comment: :Does equilibrium as stated in the previous comment means that at equilibrium:number of minority carriers(both n and p) at p-n junction that contribute in forming an depletion region would be equal?

Comment: No - what I mean is the following: The diffusion process (exchange of both carrier types across the junction) causes a depletion zone (recombination) and a corresponding diffusion voltage Vd. This voltage has a fixed value because it creates an electric field which acts against the diffusion effect. Thus, the carrier exchange stops - and we have an equilibrium between two opposite forces: (a) caused by the electric field and (b) caused by the diffusion pressure.

Comment: :Thanks.But as you said:"This voltage has a fixed value because it creates an electric field".what voltage do you mean by this?

Comment: As I have mentioned: The diffusion voltage Vd with a value of app. 0.65 volts (which must be overridden in forward operation).

Comment: :But could you say how diffusion voltage is constant?I think only on gradual increase of minority carriers transit from one region to another the diffusion voltage starts to increase.

Comment: It arrives at a fixed value because of the mentioned eqilibrium. (I am afraid we are moving in a circle)